# Calculate New Portfolio Weights Given Today's Returns

Tags: time-series, programming, portfolio-management, returns

I'm looking for a formula to recalculate my portfolio's weights at the end of time $T$, given a vector of the asset weights at $T$ and a vector of returns at $T$.

For example:

```
weights = 0.2, 0.3, 0.5
returns = 0.05, -0.05, 0.10
```

I'd like to calculate the new weighting going into $T_{t+1}$ to be based on this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the weight of the assets times the *1 + returns of the corresponding asset*.

This will give you the value of each asset at the end of your horizon.

In your example:

```
(0.2)(1+0.05) = 0.21; 
(0.3)(1+-0.05) = 0.285;
(0.5)(1+0.10) = 0.55;
```

Now add all of these values to get *Total Assets*:

```
(0.2)(1.05) + (0.3)(0.95) + (0.5)(1.10) = 1.045
```

Finally take each of the asset values and divide it by the *Total Asset Value*.

This will give you the weight of each asset at end of the horizon.

```
Weight A = 0.21/1.045 = 0.200957; 
Weight B = 0.285/1.045 = 0.272727; 
Weight C = 0.55/1.045 = 0.526316;

Weight(0) * return / Sum(weight * return) = Weight(t);
```